# Python request lib file upload from stdin

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I would like to upload/send the data from the standard output  using request Python library. [Documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) says that `data` can be bytes, dictionary or file-like object but when I pass `sys.stdin` (which should be a file-like object) it simply sends no data.

**script.py**:

```
import sys, requests

requests.put('http://localhost:8080/test', sys.stdin)
print "done"
```

Invoked with

```
echo "lore ipsum" | python test.py
```

or

```
python test.py
```

with `Ctrl + D` to end input

The request on server is:

```
----- Request Start ----->

/test
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 0
User-Agent: python-requests/2.5.1 CPython/2.7.8 Linux/3.16.6-2-desktop
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


<----- Request End -----
```

Please not I do not want to read stdin to an array like `data = data.read()` as the file might be arbitrarily big.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something improperly?

Comment: works for me with a trivial server invoked as `nc -l -p 8080`. maybe you are seeing some buffering issues....

Comment: Strange, with `nc -l 8080` it works for me as well (I used python reflection server before). But `echo "lore ipsum" | python script.py` just blocks. Why is this so?